# Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I'm doing a sample in CN1 and in this sample we implemented service consumption as well. while parsing response we tried to convert to boolean from an Object.

Here is the code I tried

```
boolean check = new Boolean(res.get(i).get("check").toString());
```

but in this, I'm getting this error.

> Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of that, you could use `parseBoolean()`

```
boolean check = Boolean.parseBoolean(res.get(i).get("check").toString());
```

Note that `res.get(i).get("check").toString()` should be a string of one of these (True, False, true, false) for it to work accurately. `false` will be assigned to `check` for any other value.

Comment: same like this only or(||) operator also its not allowing.. what is the solution for this?

Comment: Can you ask that on a separate question and I will answer it. Post some code snippets.

Comment: another question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46743714/com-codename1-l10n-parseexception-invalid-timezone-value-in-codenameone