# com.codename1.l10n.ParseException: Invalid timezone value in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I'm doing a sample in CN1 and in this sample i tried to convert the date from one pattern to another.

here is method what i'm using :

```
    private String convertDateFormat(String fromDate) {

    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

    Date d= null;
    try {
        d = df.parse(fromDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    System.out.println(df.format(d));

    return df.format(d);
}
```

calling the method

```
String convertedDate = convertDateFormat("Sun Aug 14 16:13:39 GMT+05:30 2016");
```

and above code is working in simulator but when i runs in the device i'm getting this 
"com.codename1.l10n.ParseException: Invalid timezone value" Exception..

How can i fix this?

Comment: The problem is from `GMT +5:00`, try removing that or change it to `GMT +5 or GMT +6`.

Comment: if that is the reason in simulator also it wont be work right and if we change the value GMT +5:30 to GMT +5 or GMT +6 will get time difference know..

Comment: The simulator supports more timezones. Timezones are a bit of a black hole in terms of portability. I would recommend wokring with the L10NManager class when possible

Comment: i don't know how to use L10NManager, can you post some code for L10NManager to better understanding..

Comment: There is a sample in the JavaDocs: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/l10n/L10NManager.html